# JSF: onfocus for PrimeFaces editor?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way for somehow listening onfocus for Primefaces p:editor?

Here's my p:editor:

```
<p:editor widgetVar="editorWidget"
    value="#{customEditorBean.content}" width="600" maxlength="8000">
```

I can find `onchange` attribute for the editor but that's it. I'm trying to implement a functionality where a save button would be enabled once user starts to write something on the editor's text field. But I don't want to do a check on every keystroke / value change, but just on the first click on the text field.

Here's the button:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveButton" action="#{customEditorBean.save}"
    update="@all" value="Save" rendered="#{customEditorBean.canSaveContent}"
    disabled="#{!customEditorBean.contentEdited}"/>
```

Comment: JSF renders plain HTML and JavaScript. You don't need to wait for PrimeFaces to support onfocus via an attribute -- just add a standard event listener.

Comment: Can you perhaps write an elaborate answer on how to do it? And I'll check mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I'm not interested in working on this right now. Good luck.